# Azure Active Directory - (Azure Resources) to seperate of concerns

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Can any Azure Active Directory gurus suggest the best answer to the following...

Currently a very large enterprise already is using Azure AD syncing onsight ADDS with Azure AD (Enterprise Azure AD/ADDS).

Is the best solution to create a new Azure AD Resource to keep seperation of concerns and to ensure that users from 1 Azure AD resource has no way of of accessing the other Azure AD resource (Enterprise Azure AD/ADDS) and is there any extra cost with create 1 to n... *(except for premium licenses, which we already pay for)*

Does 1 Azure subscription cover 1 to n....  Azure Active Directory Resources?

We want the new Azure AD to only contain out side guests aka @gmail, @yahoo, but this is all B2B.

```
---1 Overall Azure Tenant
|
 ----+ (1) Azure AD Enterprise Synce with on premise ADDS (Office 365 and a 
       lot more) (Currently Exists)
|
 ----+ (2) Azure AD Contractors with access to specific applications that are 
       configured
```

Comment: Just for confirming. What do you want to prevent guest users to access? Enterprise application or Resources in Azure subscription?  Also, you can have multiple subscriptions in one Directory, but you cannot let one subscription covers multiple directories.

Comment: The cloud architectural design I imagine is two (2) Azure Active Directories Resources in 1 Azure Tenant.   So, there is "NO" way a user from 2nd Azure AD (Contains Enterprise Sync with internal ADDS) and hosts Applications and other resources can in any way access anything in the 2nd Azure AD and vice versa.  We are wanting only outside contractors to reside in the 2nd Azure AD (w/ Premium Licensing for MFA).

Comment: More Details...
With this design our team could allow our team Global Admin rights as we are not touching the enterprise 1st Azure AD, which we cannot get access.

We have premium licensing for the 1st already and would be willing to pay for the 2nd, but would it need a second Azure Tenant Subscription?  <---  This is the real question.

---1 Overall Azure Tenant

----+ (1) Azure AD Enterprise Synce with on premise ADDS (Office 365 and a lot more) (Currently Exists)

----+ (2) Azure AD Contractors with access to specific applications that are configured

Comment: Hi @Moojjoo , Thanks for your details. I got it. 1. I assume that the "Azure subscription" you said means Azure AD license. This cannot cover multiple tenants. 2. You can achieve that you can only invite users from `gamil.com` and `yahoo.com`domains with restricting collaboration settings under user settings. You can go to Azure Portal > AAD > Users> User settings> External collaboration settings.

Comment: Wayne Yang - I believe Neelesh RayMicrosoft contingent staff, Moderator answered the question - it is possible to have 2 Azure AD resources under 1 over all Azure Subscription, but you do need to pay for the Premium licenses in either Azure AD Resource.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/ceee0f3e-5d60-40b8-be7f-fd6d79726d59/azure-active-directory-azure-resources-to-seperate-of-concerns?forum=WindowsAzureAD

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Azure Subscription you can have multiple Azure AD resources (No Extra Cost), as many as you want.  This allows for different Global Administrators to manage different Azure AD resources such as Users, Guests, Apps, Proxy connectors.

However, this does go without saying that you still have to pay for the Premium licenses if needed in each AD Azure Resource should you need them.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/